# Is there a "modified" field?

Tags: rss

I read some rss feed from my application, and as some articles can be updated on the site, I wanted to know if there is a field I can look at, in order to see if I'm getting the same article or a modified version.
I know there's a ttl field, but it is just an hint of how long I can keep the article in the cache: it doesn't actually say if it was really updated or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't mean something like [the cloud element](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html#ltcloudgtSubelementOfLtchannelgt) there isn't any.

> "Its purpose is to allow processes to register with a cloud to be notified of updates to the channel, implementing a lightweight publish-subscribe protocol for RSS feeds."

See [the list of elements](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html#requiredChannelElements) at w3.org.